# Templates in React

Tags: templates, web, reactjs

I've been trying to learn `React` through building my own website by using it, and have come to a point where I'm very tempted to use `jinja2` templates. I understand the component paradigm pretty well, but am having a hard time piecing together the larger picture.

For example, let's say I'm building http://www.imgur.com

For the components, I might write a image `card component` for each image, perhaps a `mouseover component` for the short summary of each image, etc...

However, how am I suppose to put the larger pieces together? In `jinja2`, I can just extend a base template or include a header/footer. What is the proper way to do that sort of thing in `React`? I'd like to get rid of conventional templates altogether.

Comment: there's lots of examples of how to compose components, both in React docs, and elsewhere. You might want to get more specific in your question and show some code with what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I understand components very well from a low level view, I just don't understand how to glue them all together in a top level view. Am I suppose to just... 'componentize' literally everything, including components that are only used once, like the header menu as well as whole pages?

Comment: You're assessment is correct. Single use components are very common. The value of componentizing hierarchies is as much (or more) for code organization as code reuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you definitely have the right idea, and you will just need to expand upon it a little bit. If you already have the "card" component, and the "mouseover" component, you would just need to add something like a "homePage" component that would be composed of the other components.

For example, your render method in the "homePage" component might look something like this:

```
render() {
  var menuItems = ['sign in', 'sign up'];
  return (
    <div>
      <navbar menuItems={menuItems} />
      <card attr1="Card1" />
      <card attr1="Card2" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So, everything is suppose to be a component... including entire pages?

Comment: Basically, yes. In fact, your entire page, could be a single component that just has raw HTML in it (not that you would want to do that for maintainability reasons however).

Comment: +1. I would also add that most components should be *composable*. So you would have a `Card` component and route view components, but you could also have *behaviours* (like `mouseover`) that extend the functionality of a component without rendering anything new. Behaviours are higher-order components (HOCs) that make dumb components smart without altering them. The vast majority of your components should be pure, dumb functions: `const Header = ({ title, children }) => ( <div><h1>{title}</h1><div>{children}</div></div>`. Using is easy: `<Header title="Hello">{/* ... */}</Header>`.

Comment: Got ya! I sort of new what I had to do, but it didn't 'feel' right. Any who, that was super helpful, thanks a ton gentleman.